# Apache itk зависает из-за Zend opcache

Tags: apache, zend-framework, php7

Доброго времени и суток.

Имеется несколько серверов, работающих в связке:

> debian 8 + nginx (front-end) apache2 itk (back-end) + php7 dotdeb
>   пакетный.

Настройки opcache в php.ini

```
opcache.max_accelerated_files=10000
opcache.memory_consumption=256
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=16
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Периодически на любых из нескольких серверов происходят зависания apache, помогает только его перезапуск.
Характер зависаний следующий. Случайным образом и в случайное время, все процессы apache начинают спать (состояние sleep), при этом имеет место быть резкий рост количества процессов apache, который  достигает лимита, в итоге получаем 200 apache процессов от пользователя www, которые просто ждут своих 200 разных пользовательских `itk потомков`, а эти потомки в свою очередь ждут `F_WRLK` на `ZendSem`, которые ждут не понятно чего, при этом, если попытаться открыть любой сайт от любого пользователя, ничего не выйдет и после длительного ожидания - `504-я ошибка apache`. В нормальном, даже в очень нагруженном состоянии количество процессов не более 50.

Если рассмотреть потомка поближе, то имеем такое:

```
strace -p 24209
Process 24209 attached
fcntl(2981, F_SETLKW, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=1}
```

2981 дескриптор указывает на:

```
apache2 24209 user1213 2981u REG 253,0 0 22074361 /tmp/.ZendSem.rz9P8a (deleted)
```

И так с каждым процессом.

**opcache.enable=0** - вроде решает проблему, случайные зависания исчезают, но тогда теряется смысл и невозможно использовать opcache.

/tmp это не отдельный раздел в системе, места на диске достаточно - это SSD.

Может кто-то с подобным тоже сталкивался и есть какие-либо пути решения этой проблемы?